# GitLab Dynamically run jobs in parallel

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project which generate go main files in folders which follow certain convention. The problem is I need to build those projects parallelly in Gitlab CI pipeline when there is a code push and I cant hardcode them in `.gitlab-ci.yml` as they are generated on fly. I need to build those go projects in parallel and need to pass build stage if all the individual project builds are succeeded. Can someone please let me know if it is possible in Gitlab.

Comment: Gitlab CI allows you to run any script you want. You'll have to expand on what you're struggling with that can't be solved with `find` and `parallel` in bash. Do you want to run each project as a separate job? Cause that's not supported as of now: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/50572 . Of course this can be done but the solutions won't be pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately gitlab CI doesn't support this it seems as per https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23455. As mentioned in this issue and @Jakub, I am looking for something like this(Some glob or template sort of solution) so that I could parallelize jobs on fly:

```
build_%:
  image: dnd
  stage: build
  glob: microservices/*/Dockerfile
  context: microservices/{1}
  script:
    - docker build  {1}
 parallel: true
```

So I have decided to use [go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for now until Gitlab CI comes with one solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is now also possible using the [child pipelines feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines).
You can use YTT to generate the YAML configuration file for child pipelines - but any generation method can be used as long as you provide a valid YAML file.

> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
generate-config:
  stage: build
  script: ytt -f config-template.yml -f config-template-values.yml --data-value-yaml services="[${SERVICES}]" > generated-config.yml # with SERVICES=service1,service2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-config.yml

child-pipeline:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-config.yml
        job: generate-config
```

> config-template.yml

```
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
stages:
  - test
#@ for service in data.values.services:
#@yaml/text-templated-strings
(@= service @)-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - #@ "test " + service
#@ end
```

> config-template-values.yml

```
#@data/values
---
services: []
```